# how to out put Php variable in html element attribute in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have the following code

```
@php

    $id = some integer
    echo  '<'.input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="$id". '>'
@endphp
```

how can i use this `$id` variable inside `html` element attribute

it produce  the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   ',' or ';' (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\post\userposts.blade.php)

Comment: Your code is so full of parsing errors, that even when you fix that first one at least three others should occur one after another. This does not even look related to PHP code. Are you sure that this is not some template engine you are working with?

Answer (score 4):

You already are in a blade template, just use blade and its syntax:

```
@php
 $id = whatever you need
@endphp

<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
```

As you see you can use your variables with the special quotation `{{ $var }}`

Comment: this doesn't work it produce  undefined variable error

Comment: it should, check your variable definition, also, I suggest you defining it on your controller and passing it to the view, instead of defining on the view itself

Comment: i need  it in view

Comment: Then check the syntax on your definition, pay special attention to colon, semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. You just need to search it.

```
@php
   $id = some integer
@endphp

<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

or

```
@php

$id = some integer
echo  '<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="'.$id.'">';

@endphp
```

or

```
@php
   $id = some integer
@endphp

<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
```

I suggest to call the `$id` from controller or the value of `$id`.

Comment: but this variable is not accessible out side of the ending tag of php

Comment: Try using "<?php $id = some integer; echo '$id';?>".

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use semicolon at the end of the line:

```
$id = 111;// some integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is wrong, you should pay attention to what you wrote, here is the good way of making it work:

```
$id = 5;
echo  '<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="' . $id . '">';
```

Comment: this  is not passing value of id

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work ..

```
<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?=echo $id;?>"
```

OR

```
 <input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"
```

Comment: this produce the following out put is value of id <?php echo $id;?>"

Comment: that woould indicate that the PHP is not being loaded at all.

Comment: if you leave only "@php    $id=someInteger; echo $id; @endphp" and itt displays nothing then then php engine is not even parsing the doc